# How to integrate the following function

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Calculate 
$$
\int\frac{dx}{1+\mathrm{erf}(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x,
$$ 
where $\mathrm{erf}$ is the error function. It is known that $\int \mathrm{erf}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=x\,\mathrm{erf}(x)+\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\mathrm{erf}(x)=\frac{2 e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}.$

Comment: I suppose that you want the definite integral between some bounds. What is the largest upper bound you need to deal with ? I could provide a table of values from which you could build your interpolating function. Just let me know. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let $u=\mathrm{erf}(x)$ ,

Then $x=\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(u)$

$dx=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{2}e^{(\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(u))^2}~du$ (according to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErf.html)

$\therefore\int\dfrac{dx}{1+\mathrm{erf}(x)}=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\int\dfrac{e^{(\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(u))^2}}{u+1}~du$

Comment: I suppose that we could do it for any function $$\int \frac {dx}{1+f(x)}=\int\frac{dt}{(t+1) f'\left(f^{(-1)}(t)\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that $$I=\int \frac{dx}{1+\text{erf}(x)}$$ could be expressed in terms of any function (even special functions) and more than likely, numerical integration would be required.

Computing $$F(t)=\int_0^t \frac{dx}{1+\text{erf}(x)}$$ reveals a trend very close to linear as shown in the table below 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 t & F(t) \\
 1 & 0.69402 \\
 2 & 1.20690 \\
 3 & 1.70714 \\
 4 & 2.20715 \\
 5 & 2.70715 \\
 6 & 3.20715 \\
 7 & 3.70715 \\
 8 & 4.20715 \\
 9 & 4.70715 \\
 10 & 5.20715
\end{array}
\right)$$ where you see that to a $\Delta t=1$ corresponds a $\Delta F(t)=\frac12$.

If $t$ as to be small (say $0\leq t \leq 1$) you could use Taylor series built, for the integrand, around $x=0$ $$\frac{1}{1+\text{erf}(x)}=1-\frac{2 x}{\sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{4 x^2}{\pi }+\frac{2 (\pi -12) x^3}{3 \pi
   ^{3/2}}-\frac{8 (\pi -6) x^4}{3 \pi ^2}+\frac{\left(-160+40 \pi -\pi ^2\right)
   x^5}{5 \pi ^{5/2}}+\frac{8 \left(360-120 \pi +7 \pi ^2\right) x^6}{45 \pi
   ^3}+\frac{\left(-13440+5600 \pi -532 \pi ^2+5 \pi ^3\right) x^7}{105 \pi
   ^{7/2}}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ which will give, as an approximation, $$F(t)=t-\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{4 t^3}{3 \pi }+\frac{(\pi -12) t^4}{6 \pi
   ^{3/2}}-\frac{8 (\pi -6) t^5}{15 \pi ^2}+\frac{\left(-160+40 \pi -\pi
   ^2\right) t^6}{30 \pi ^{5/2}}+\frac{8 \left(360-120 \pi +7 \pi ^2\right)
   t^7}{315 \pi ^3}+\frac{\left(-13440+5600 \pi -532 \pi ^2+5 \pi ^3\right)
   t^8}{840 \pi ^{7/2}}+O\left(t^9\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 t & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
0.0  & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
 0.1 & 0.094758 & 0.094758 \\
 0.2 & 0.180448 & 0.180448 \\
 0.3 & 0.258857 & 0.258856 \\
 0.4 & 0.331400 & 0.331398 \\
 0.5 & 0.399212 & 0.399197 \\
 0.6 & 0.463209 & 0.463135 \\
 0.7 & 0.524135 & 0.523848 \\
 0.8 & 0.582595 & 0.581672 \\
 0.9 & 0.639088 & 0.636506 \\
 1.0 & 0.694020 & 0.687561
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you need to resuse mutliple times, what I would suggest is to generate a table of $F(t)$ for the range of interest, build a cubic spline (or nay interpolating function).

**Edit**

As shown above, using Taylor series, even for the range $0\leq t \leq 1$, the results are not very good in spite of the large number of terms used. I think that we can do better consider instead a very limited Padé approximant which is 
$$\frac{1}{1+\text{erf}(x)}=\frac{\frac{x^2}{3}+1}{\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{2 x}{\sqrt{\pi }}+1}$$ which would lead to $$F(t)=x+6
   \sqrt{\frac{3}{(\pi -3) \pi }} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi } x+3}{\sqrt{3
   (\pi -3)}}\right)-\frac{3 \log \left(\sqrt{\pi } \left(x^2+3\right)+6 x\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}-C$$ where $$C=6 \sqrt{\frac{3}{(\pi -3) \pi }} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi
   -3}}\right)-\frac{3 \log \left(3 \sqrt{\pi }\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$

This would give 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 t & \text{exact} & \text{Padé} \\
 0.0 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
 0.1 & 0.094758 & 0.094758 \\
 0.2 & 0.180448 & 0.180448 \\
 0.3 & 0.258857 & 0.258856 \\
 0.4 & 0.331400 & 0.331396 \\
 0.5 & 0.399212 & 0.399200 \\
 0.6 & 0.463209 & 0.463179 \\
 0.7 & 0.524135 & 0.524071 \\
 0.8 & 0.582595 & 0.582481 \\
 0.9 & 0.639088 & 0.638900 \\
 1.0 & 0.694020 & 0.693737
\end{array}
\right)$$ which looks to be much better.